# if someone says "My {insert a body part} is better" which one of these would you use: "yeah, but your face isn't" vs "yeah, but your face doesn't"

Tags: sentence-choice

I am sorry for taking the time to ask this silly question but it has been bugging me quite a bit. There was a twitter argument (as is usual for twitter) and an OF model said that about one of her body parts. a guy replied

"yeah, but your face doesn't"

and then I questioned

"shouldn't it be 'yeah, but your face isn't'?"

But that guy's sentence doesn't seem wrong either. I am really confused here. which one of these sentences would a native speaker use in that context?

Comment: Please link to the conversation on twitter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no other context, it would have to be, "Your face isn't" as it is a shortening of "Your face isn't better".